# Link Clicks while animating in Android

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I've got 3 blocks of text, which contain various things that may be linked (such as web addresses, physical addresses, etc.) and the blocks of text are collapsible. While doing the animation to collapse/expand the text, if one of the links is clicked, the animation does weird things. So I'm trying to disable links inside of the `TextView` while the animation is happening.

I've got an `AnimationListener`, but I'm not sure what to do in it in order to disable the links. I've tried using `TextView.setClickable(false)`, and `TextView.setLinksClickable(false)`, but neither seems to work.

I've currently got the links being created automatically using the XML attribute `android:autoLink="all"`, but I've also tried removing that and using `TextView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL)` instead.

Is there any way for me to disable clicking these links after the link has been created?